# How to clone destroyed objects in unity3D?

Tags: c#, object, scripting, unity-game-engine, clone

I made a wall that get destroyed when the character touches it and then he can keep walking. I want to create the same wall after few seconds or after the character pass it , anyone knows how do it ? ( I already tried it with a timer and OnCollisionExit but it didn't seem to work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. store a reference to your object (probably in your player script)
2. Set it to inactive with [GameObject.SetActive(false)](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) when you're
3. ready (your OnCollisionExit or timer function), set it to active.